# DC Power Outages

Tags: opportunity, nature-recording

Following the massive storm that knocked out power to many areas on the East Coast, I'm just wondering if anyone is taking advantage of the lack of air conditioners humming and grabbing some nice residential BGs or other sounds. From the way my friends are facebooking, it sounds like entire neighborhoods are ghost towns.

Comment: Excellent point, Steve. This would be an ideal time to capture some beautiful nature recordings in and around neighborhoods that are normally polluted by all manner of noise and traffic that is most likely absent right now.

Comment: You'd think that, but the odd generator here and there is worse than the residential and commercial HVAC. At least, it was in my area.

Comment: oh, Steve would know that there's NEVER no traffic in the DC area. ;)